# Unable to combine words in Files by Zsh/AWK

Tags: awk, zsh

I have File1

```
A,B,C
```

and File2

```
D,E,F
```

I am trying to have

```
AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF, CD, CE, CF
```

unsuccessfully by

```
echo {`cat File1`}{`cat File2`}
```

giving

```
{A,B,C}{D,E,F}
```

**How can you solve the problem by Zsh/AWK?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '
    NR==FNR {
        # read lines from File1 into the array f1
        f1[NR]=$0
        next
    }
    {
        # foreach line in File2
        split(f1[FNR], words);    # get words from corresponding line in File1
        sep = ""
        for (i in words) {
            for (j=1; j<=NF; j++) {
                printf("%s%s%s", sep, words[i], $j)
                sep = ", "
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
' File1 File2
```

If File1 contains

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
```

and File2 contains

```
D,E,F
4,5,6
```

then the awk script outputs

```
AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF, CD, CE, CF
14, 15, 16, 24, 25, 26, 34, 35, 36
```

Comment: looking back on this, now I'd write `n = split(...)` and then `for(i=1; i<=n; i++) { ...` because `for (i in words)` is not guaranteed to return the indices in any particular order.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know zsh, here's what I did with bash and sed:

```
echo "A,B,C" >a
echo "D,E,F" >b
for i in `cat a | sed -e "s@,@\n@g"`; 
      do for j in `cat b | sed -e "s@,@\n@g"`; 
      do echo -n "$i$j, "; 
      done ; 
      done | sed -e "s@,\s\$@@"
```

The output then is:

```
AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF, CD, CE, CF
```